# Get average accuracy of the coordinate

Tags: android, gps, location, here-api

I have a model with data like this:

```
data class GeoCoordinate (
val latitude: Double,
val longitude: Double,
val altitude: Double? = null,

val longitudeAccuracy: Float,
val latitudeAccuracy: Float,
val altitudeAccuracy: Float
)
```

This data is coming from [HERE api](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/common/GeoPosition.html) and GPS sensors of phone.

I want to understand - how can I calculate average value of accuracy to display it to user?

I'm also see standard android documentation about [Location](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy()) - they include only 'horizontal' accuracy (without altitude param). But I don't know how to calc accuracy from two params - `longitudeAccuracy` and `latitudeAccuracy`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of GPS positioning (or other GNSS positioning), both *latitudeAccuracy* and *longitudeAccuracy* values of the *GeoPosition* class should be equal to the "horizontal accuracy" of *android.location.Location*, since the Android SDK does not provide the accuracy "per axis".

Therefore, pick either of them and you have the horizontal accuracy in CEP68 meters (Circular Error Probable 68%), meaning that if you render a circle of such radius around the estimated location, there are 68% chances that the actual location falls inside that circle.

That said, for positioning methods that would return different values for *latitudeAccuracy* and *longitudeAccuracy*, the resulting "horizontal accuracy" should be the maximum of both values, not an average of those.